# PostgreSQL 9.5 Create Publication?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.5, google-bigquery

Based on the [official doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createpublication.html), `CREATE PUBLICATION` command is available on PostgreSQL 10 and later. However, I have a requirement to replicate PostgreSQL 9.5 to BigQuery using datastream, which [require us](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/configure-your-source-postgresql-database#selfhostedpostgresql) to create a publication and a replication slot.

My question, can I create a [pglogical node and replication set](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical#quick-setup) to achieve the same result as `CREATE PUBLICATION` command?

Command using pglogical:

```
SELECT pglogical.create_node(
    node_name := 'provider1',
    dsn := 'host=server_host port=5432 dbname=db_name'
);

SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_all_tables('default', ARRAY['public']);
```

Command using publication:

```
CREATE PUBLICATION db_publication FOR ALL TABLES;
```

After above command, we need to create the replication slot with the following command:

```
SELECT PG_CREATE_LOGICAL_REPLICATION_SLOT('slot_name', 'pgoutput');
```

which seems [are available](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/logicaldecoding-example.html) on PostgreSQL 9.5.

If it's not possible to only use pglogical command, is there any alternative to replicate the DB to BigQuery? Thanks

Comment: Upgrade PostgreSQL rather than toying with fickle replication solutions.